# protoc-c: Nested structure with optional string throws seg fault

Tags: c, serialization, deserialization, protocols, protocol-buffers

Trying out Google protocol buffers for my code in C language.

```html
messagefile.proto
===================
mesage othermessage
{
  optional string otherstring = 1;
}

message onemessage
{
  optional string messagestring = 1;
  optional int32 aninteger      = 2;
  optional othermessage otr_message= 3;
}
```

==============================================

--> protoc-c messagefile.proto --c_out=./
this resulted in two files

## --> messagefile.pb-c.c and messagefile.pb-c.h

Now my code file which would try to use the 
simpleexample.c

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "messagefile.pb-c.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    onemessage msg = ONE__MESSAGE__INIT; //from generated .h  code file
    void *buf;
    unsigned int len;
    char *ptr;

    //integer initialization 
    msg.has_aninteger = true;
    msg.aninteger = 1;

    //accessing the string in onemessage
    msg.messagestring = malloc(sizeof("a simple string"));
    strncpy(msg.messagestring,"a simple string",strlen("a simple string"));

    //trying to initialize the string in the nested structure othermessage        
    msg.otr_message = malloc(sizeof(othermessage));
    msg.otr_message->otherstring = malloc(sizeof("a not so simple string"));
    strncpy(msg.otr_message->otherstring,"a not so simple string",strlen("a not so simple string"));

    //lets find the length of the packed structure
    len = one_message__get_packed_size(&msg); //from generated .h code
 
    //lets arrange for as much size as len
    buf = malloc(len);

    //lets get the serialized structure in buf
    one_message__pack_to_buffer(&msg,buf); //from generated code

    //write it to a stream, for now the screen
    fwrite(buf,len,1,stdout);

    //free buffer
    free(buf);
     
     return 0;
}
```

I compile it as gcc -o testout messagefile.pb-c.c simpleexample.c -lprotobuf-c

The Problem I am facing is when trying to initialize the nested othermessage variables and then call the get_packed_size it throws a segmentation fault.

I tried various combinations and I can say that whenever having strings in a nested class, I am facing problem to access those using google protoc.
Am i missing something? Is there anything wrong.

Can anyone please help.

note:There might be a few general syntax errors please ignore them.

ThankYou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> note:There might be a few general syntax errors please ignore them.

Err... they are kinda hard to ignore since your code does not compile :-)

Anyway, apart from the syntax errors, you need to make several corrections to your code. In order to use the field `otr_message`, it is not sufficient to just `malloc()` it. You also need to initialize it so the headers in the message get the right values. This is done with `init()`, like this:

```
//trying to initialize the string in the nested structure othermessage        
msg.otr_message = malloc(sizeof(othermessage));
othermessage__init(msg.otr_message);
```

Then you use the wrong function to do the packing to your own array. As explained [here](http://lib.protobuf-c.io/pack.html), you need to use `pack()` as opposed to `pack_to_buffer()`, like this:

```
//lets get the serialized structure in buf
onemessage__pack(&msg,buf); //from generated code
```

Finally, your `strncpy()` invocations have a mistake. The length calculated with `strlen()` does not include the null terminator, which you do need. So you need to take `strlen()+1` or use `sizeof()`, like this:

```
strncpy(msg.messagestring,"a simple string",sizeof("a simple string"));
```

After making those changes, the example worked for me:

```
$ ./testout 

a simple string
a not so simple string
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..Your directions helped me solve the problem. I however still wish that the protocol buffer documentation was written in a better way. Thanks Again. :)

Comment: You are welcome. Since you are new on Stack Overflow, check out [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)